# Browser compatibility issues

Tags: web-development, website-design, browsers

I am fairly new to website design. I am currently coding a new site. I have a local server setup (localhost) using Apache and testing using Firefox Ver 21 and IE Ver 9. I am getting display differences between Firefox and IE. I am confused about IE compatibility mode. For my testing should IE compatibility mode in IE be set on (checked I suppose) or off (unchecked)? Any other suggestions on how to ensure the displays will be correct on different versions of IE? If I get the display like I want it in Firefox, some aspect is different in IE with compatibility off. If I turn compatibility on it might fix one issue but screw up another. I guess I just don't understand the correct process to attack the compatibility issues between browsers, if that makes any sense. Doing all the layout in CSS.

Comment: Also: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10865/how-can-i-test-my-web-site-in-ie6-ie7-ie8-and-ie9/10876